# Voltage Converter Circuit

Tags: driver, rs232, receiver

I am using [SN75188](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn55188.pdf) for converting 5V,0V 16 kHz square wave to -7V,7V 16 kHz square wave and using [SN75189](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/slls095d/slls095d.pdf) to process opposite convertion. I have shown the dataheet information of them. I considered that i considered that i can do this operations with these ICs. Am i right? That was my first question. The second is i cannot find any information related to frequency range of ICs. Is 16 kHz signal value available for operation? If you share your idea, i will be happy.

[SN75188](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn55188.pdf) Datahseet Information:

[image]

[SN75189](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/slls095d/slls095d.pdf) Datahseet Information:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the transition times in the datasheet. These depends on the load capacitance and therefore determine the maximum frequency and how square your waves will be.

16kHz doesn't seem particularly onerous to me and I can't really see any reason why these wouldn't do what you want.